# Trivial Summation Challenge

Tags: limits, summation, fractions

Write the repeating decimal $1.367367367367...$ in the form $a/b$ where both $a$ an $b$ are positive whole numbers, but do this using a converging infinite sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your numer as 
$$1+0.367367\dots$$
and notice that the latter term can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{367}{10^{3n}}.$$
Now notice that this is nothing but an infinite geometric series. Conclude.

Answer (score 3):

And,
ignoring the requirement
for an infinite sum,
if
$x=1.367367367367...$,
then
$1000x = 1367.367367367...
$
so
$999x = 1366$
so
$x = \dfrac{1366}{999}
$.